# Help with PHP IF statement - OR AND etc

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a little problem. I wish to create an IF statement, that shall react like this:

- If user is NOT admin (forum_admin) AND they are not the owner of the ticket (userid), BUT moderators are allowed to view tickets (allow_moderator_tickets) AND user is moderator (forum_moderator), then he should be allowed to view the ticket.

How can I obtain this with a PHP if statement.

So far I have this:

```
 //If user is not allowed to view.  
    if($userdata['forum_admin']==0 && $ticketDetails['userid']!=$userdata['id'] || $sdata['allow_moderator_ticket']==0 && $userdata['forum_moderator']==1)
        redirect("?i=a");
```

Comment: Yes, admins SHOULD be allowed no matter what.

Comment: I think you make it too complicated. Take the conditions that ALLOW a user to view the ticket one by one, connect them via OR and finally `!()` this. (Of course you should also `()` conditions that consist of several subconditions to avoid operator precedence issues.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if ( isAdmin || (allowModerators && isModerator) || userID == ticketUser ) allowToSeeTicket

 if ( ! (isAdmin || (allowModerators && isModerator) || userID == ticketUser) ) notAllowToSeeTicket
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mix and and or operators. each other will spoil another.
you should group your expressions, using parenthesis, much like in arithmetics

it would be nice to refactor your code to make it readable

```
$admin = ($userdata['forum_admin']);
$owner = ($ticketDetails['userid'] == $userdata['id']);
$moder = ($sdata['allow_moderator_ticket'] == 1 AND $userdata['forum_moderator']==1)

if !($admin OR $moder OR $owner) {
    redirect("?i=a");
}
```